# How can i delete a specific element from a linked list?

Tags: java

I'm getting the name and average of some people, but i need to delete one of them based on his average (the user choses which one to delte), how can i do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = input.next();
    double avr = input.nextInt();
    Node first = new Node(name, avr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println("enter name");
        name = input.next();
        System.out.println("enter avr");
        avr = input.nextInt();
        Node second = new Node(name, avr);
        second.next = first;
        first = second;
    }
    Node temp = first;
    double delete;
    System.out.println("avr of person you want to delete");
    delete = input.nextInt();
    while (temp != null) {
        if (delete == (temp.avr)) {

            //delete

            System.out.println("delete this guy");
            break;
        } else {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to set the previous person's pointer to the pointer of the person you would like to delete from the linked list.

Comment: Here´s the logic, additionally store the previous `Node`. if the current `Node` does have the `avr` you want to "delete" set `next` from the previous `Node` to the current `Node`'s `next` (if there is one, if not just `null` it).

Comment: why don't you use a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete = input.nextInt();
if (temp.avr == delete){
    first = temp.next;
}
else{
    while (temp != null && temp.next != null) {
        if (delete == (temp.next.avr)) {
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
            System.out.println("delete this guy");
            break;
        } else {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: In order to delete the relevant node you update its previous node to point to its next.

And, since we're always checking if `temp.next == delete`, we have to check first if the node that needs to be deleted is the first node and delete it accordingly.

**NOTE:** The suggested code above should work specifically for the example you supplied. But, in general, I would suggest to always add conditions for all possible cases, such as `first == null` or the node to be deleted was not found and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Simply traverse the linked-list with two pointers (references). One would search for the node that is to be deleted and the other would be just behind this pointer.

```
Node prev = null;
Node curr = first;

while((curr != null) && (curr.avr != delete)) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr.next;
}

if(curr == null) {
    // not found
}
else if(prev == null) {
    // first element
    first = first.next;
}
else {
    prev.next = curr.next;
}
```

NOTE: Comparison of doubles for equality doesn't work. You can compare for only less than or greater than. Read about precision issues with respect to double (floating-point) comparisons. I would suggest you use integer for the average in case you have to compare for equality.